# Android Studio setting background of an Imagebutton

Tags: android, imagebutton

```
public class Game_Screen extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageButton b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_menue);
        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.imbttn1));
    }

    public void test(View v){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
    }
}
```

I want to change the background image of some buttons after one button is pressed.  Using the View works fine. But if I try to change an imagebutton specifically I get this from the logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.loan.fastclickerv30.Game_Screen.test(Game_Screen.java:43)

This is the XML code for the imagebutton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imbttn1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewLevel"
    android:onClick="test" />
```

Comment: please post activity_start_menue.xml

Comment: 2 questions... where are you calling 'test'?  and being an ImageButton, you'd want to setImageResource, rather than background resource.  ImageResource gives you all the fun imageview funtions (like scaletype and whatnot) where backgroundResource just fits an image to the background

Comment: Your error exactly tells you what's wrong. You tried to call a function on an object that isn't set. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`. And where are you caling `test(View)`btw ?

Comment: Test() is being called by the button after it is pressed. What do you mean by set? I think i did everything I need to do with     ImageButton b1= (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.imbttn1));

Answer (score 3):

You were creating a local variable of b1 instead of assigning it to the real one. Use this code.

```
public class Game_Screen extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageButton b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_menue);
        b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.imbttn1));
    }

    public void test(View v){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You receive `NullPointerException` because b1 is null. You have two b1 variable, one inside `onCreate` and one in the class `Game_Screen`. You never assign the one in class `Game_Screen`. Change your code like this:

```
public class Game_Screen extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageButton b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_menue);
        b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.imbttn1));
    }

    public void test(View v){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. You've mistakenly created a local b1 variable and you're using the instance variable in the 'test' method, which is null.

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new to StackOverflow. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageButton b1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imbttn1);
```

b1 is likely null. If this is the case, then your button is may not be called imbttn1 in the xml as you're expecting. Confirm the id in XML and double check that b1 has a value.

Comment: You must be right. Doing this
b1=(ImageButton)v; and 
b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_testbackground); works. But i do not understand why b1 is null. I added the XML code. It's ID is set as imbttn1

Comment: The XML posted shows the exact same name. So this is not the problem.

Comment: He just posted the XML code. It wasn't posted before, hence why I suggested to check the ID in the XML.